# Firefox is using too much memory and is freezing my machine

Tags: firefox, memory-usage

I have some 40 machines in our company. They are running Ubuntu 14.04 with 4Gigs of RAM. Very recently I noticed that almost on all machines Firefox browser is using around 1.2 to 1.5 GB of RAM and making my computer freeze.
Can someone help me in resolving the issue?

Comment: aren't you using swappiness?

Answer (score 0):

From experience, I would recommend installing Chromium Browser and comparing the memory usage. It's hard to say whether the amount of RAM your system is consuming for Firefox is normal or not as it all depends on what your browsers are doing and what sites they are visiting.

Speaking out of personal experience, I've found chromium browser to be less resource intensive than FireFox. Others may have had differing experiences. If I were in your shoes, I'd get FireFox uninstalled and stick with Chromium.